# how to increase the distinction of a heatmap with specific labeling

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(c(1804L, 147L, 2982L, 263L, 1420L, 2225L, 905L, 1654L, 
2018L, 0L, 1L, 1649L, 53L, 1388L, 830L, 0L, 217L, 85L, 831L, 
15499L, 37394L, 568L, 216L, 498L, 78L, 696L, 1831L, 1098L, 3283L, 
2683L, 1L, 2L, 25896L, 114L, 2597L, 2476L, 0L, 83L, 65L, 2983L, 
62277L, 43394L, 3836L, 181L, 4565L, 460L, 4780L, 3961L, 1017L, 
691L, 2348L, 0L, 0L, 1987L, 20L, 831L, 4269L, 0L, 7L, 58L, 64L, 
1670L, 8250L, 1074L, 92L, 4804L, 141L, 1893L, 2444L, 1045L, 1314L, 
1848L, 0L, 0L, 3352L, 50L, 1396L, 11083L, 0L, 130L, 65L, 471L, 
16847L, 24535L, 2057L, 363L, 2739L, 244L, 4473L, 1581L, 1161L, 
4366L, 7743L, 0L, 0L, 4529L, 96L, 2815L, 5407L, 0L, 2451L, 273L, 
14016L, 209852L, 192321L, 791L, 140L, 434L, 143L, 1036L, 1012L, 
264L, 1279L, 987L, 0L, 0L, 4834L, 60L, 1952L, 489L, 0L, 39L, 
29L, 502L, 10482L, 17520L, 2259L, 280L, 1817L, 398L, 3318L, 2375L, 
729L, 2214L, 1601L, 0L, 0L, 5894L, 58L, 4210L, 5245L, 0L, 111L, 
206L, 1683L, 34731L, 57623L, 3868L, 309L, 5879L, 398L, 6534L, 
3191L, 2218L, 2076L, 4670L, 0L, 0L, 4089L, 49L, 1891L, 1506L, 
0L, 96L, 106L, 227L, 5869L, 5844L, 6126L, 527L, 1768L, 298L, 
7844L, 1574L, 922L, 2179L, 6217L, 0L, 0L, 2588L, 42L, 1296L, 
2163L, 0L, 2L, 48L, 129L, 3031L, 18798L, 3354L, 256L, 4796L, 
366L, 4875L, 1910L, 2200L, 3631L, 10243L, 0L, 1L, 2899L, 175L, 
1555L, 6639L, 0L, 1200L, 109L, 4801L, 67661L, 78865L, 849L, 89L, 
639L, 60L, 2623L, 368L, 444L, 823L, 994L, 0L, 0L, 3063L, 25L, 
421L, 838L, 0L, 154L, 49L, 517L, 11004L, 7515L, 2244L, 594L, 
2712L, 327L, 3178L, 5659L, 1828L, 2427L, 10729L, 0L, 0L, 5371L, 
272L, 8191L, 4524L, 0L, 207L, 146L, 4249L, 66773L, 81601L), .Dim = c(21L, 
12L), .Dimnames = list(c("A149564", "A108622", "B178878", "E163072", 
"S184113", "N159216", "G0112149", "EN183160", "EM168329", "EN232793", 
"ENS277545", "E0108691", "E0115008", "E37462", "EN0775", "E0100146", 
"E7430", "ENU653", "E00168314", "T197971", "ENSG0"), c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", 
"Sample8", "Sample9", "Sample10", "Sample11", "Sample12")))
```

I try to make a heatmap and try to plot it

```
heatmap(df, col = topo.colors(16), 
        scale="none", cexRow=0.5,
        xlab = "samples", ylab =  "names",
        main = "heatmap",margins = c(5,10)
        )
```

The problem is that it does not show a heatmap while it shows a constant color for it.

I want to plot it with a color differences and also make it like below

[image]

Look at the above of the heatmap. I want to plot all 5 samples together (with a color red in the heamap on the top) then the 7 samples with a (purpule color in the top) and the rest with the green color in the top

I also want to keep the order of the names the same as in the data.

I found this post too but I could not figure out how to amend my code 
http://harrycaufield.net/severalog/2016/3/1/heatmaps-in-r-two-ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the columns from being reorder set `Colv=NA` (well documented in `?heatmap`). Note that you will not have a dendrogram if you set `Colv=NA`

To add a colorbar for the columns set `ColSideColors` (again well documented in `?heatmap`)

Because your data is right-skewed log transforming will do a good job of fixing the color of individual cells. And because your data is all > 0 I think it is better to use a sequential color palette instead of a divergent palette.

```
heatmap(log(df+1), ColSideColors = rep(c("red4","green4"), c(5,7)), Colv = NA,
        col = rev(colorspace::terrain_hcl(100)), scale="none")
```

[image]

Comment: there is an error when I use your code `dim(df)
[1]  70 190`  then I get this error 'ColSideColors' must be a character vector of length ncol(x)

Comment: the example data you supplied was 21 x 12, and in your post you say **"I want to plot all 5 samples together (with a color red in the heamap on the top) then the 7 samples with a ..."** So I marked the first 5 with red and the next 7 with green (which should have been purple). if you have 190 samples then ColSideColors = `rep(c("red4", "purple", "green4"), c(5,7, 178))` should work

Comment: I checked the real data and the one I posted they both have the same `str` just the dimention of one of them is bigger . I get this error `Error in heatmap(log(df + 1), ColSideColors = rep(c("red4", "purple",  : 
  'ColSideColors' must be a character vector of length ncol(x)`

Comment: I did it in this way too but I got the same error `ColSideColors = c(rep("gray",100),rep("blue",178))`

Comment: Please, first try the code in my answer with the data you supplied in the post, as that is what I had to work with when I created the answer. Once you know that works you can try on your real data and tweak the solution as needed to fit your real data

Comment: yes in the example data that I provided it works , but in my real data it does not work . the have the same charactristic , just the real data is bigger. Can I share my data with you ?

Comment: The error message you are receiving is telling you exactly what the problem is. In this case `ColSideColors` needs to be the same length of `ncol(df)`. So start by running `ncol(df)`. Then adjust `rep(c("red4", "purple", "green4"), c(5,7, 178))` so that it returns a vector the same length as `ncol(df)`.

Comment: I even did it like this  c(5,7, ncol(df))) but gave me the same error. I shared with you the data and I would appreciate if you could have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165301/discussion-between-emilliman5-and-nik).

Comment: `c(5,7, ncol(df))` creates a vector that has a length greater than `ncol(df)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is mainly the huge difference between the numbers in your matrix

If for example you take the log of the values (+1 to avoid zeros) your heatmap will look way better:

```
df0=log(df+1)
heatmap(df0, col = topo.colors(16), 
        scale="none", cexRow=0.5,
        xlab = "samples", ylab =  "names",
        main = "heatmap",margins = c(5,10)
)
```

[image]

Comment: please read my question. I want to keep the order of the names the same as the data and make the samples in a spepcific order with color